# Computer restarted while python still running but now won't recover

Tags: python, terminal

My code has been running for 3 days now and my computer suddenly restarted, and my code won't continue where it left off. I get the following:

```
  [Restored Jun 27, 2018 at 6:22:51 PM]
Last login: Wed Jun 27 18:22:43 on console
Restored session: Wed Jun 27 18:09:53 CEST 2018
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

I've changed nothing in terms of location of files etc. How can I make it continue where it left off without having to start it all over again? I stupidly only made it write the results into a csv file once all the results are collected, so now I basically have nothing.

Comment: Based on what you've described, what you want is not possible. Sorry. Consider modifying your code to save intermediate results to disk in case this happens again.

Comment: @pault yikes I was afraid of that. I've still got all the results sitting in the terminal but it has also truncated a lot of the results, which I don't know how to resolve. Basically I can copy it all into a csv file but the format is completely wrong

Comment: why don't u save your result in a database every time that you find them? or you can use a csv file but format the information before write them